# Where cv::adaptiveBilateralFilter has disappeared?

Tags: c++, opencv

In OpenCV 2.4.9 there is a nice function `cv::adaptiveBilateralFilter()`. It is documented  here http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=bilateralfilter#adaptivebilateralfilter

In OpenCV 3 (from GIT) all references to it has been removed. Even sample code is gone.

Can anybody explain reasons for removing it. Probably some other way to use `cv::bilateralFilter()` as adaptive? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its been removed from 2.4 because of low quality.

( search https://github.com/Itseez/opencv for 'removed ABF' ).

But anything can happen as opencv-3 is not yet released. I guess, we just have to wait for the official changelog and perhaps alternate functionality.

Comment: Wow yes. 
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/2232
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/2299
This is strange. Function worked very well for me.